# IE not updating DOM with CSS3 calc function

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive site which utilizes CSS3 function calc. The basic idea is to keep the structure intact height-wise when window height is changed. The div with class "componentContent" should always alter its size according to surrounding elements. When the contents inside this div overflows, a scrollbar should appear and contents become scrollable.

With Firefox this structure works flawlessly and with Chrome it's not as fluent but still works. The problem is with IE (tried with version 11). With IE calc function doesn't seem to work and "componentContent" div is not altering its height according to window height.

I'm also looking for other ways of implementing similar structure and functionality. If someone has an idea how to improve this solution or do it in a totally different way, I'm listening!

The stucture is seen below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="menu">

        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="componentHeader">
                    Component header
                </div>
                <div class="componentContent">
                    <div style="height: 150px;">
                        contents...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="componentFooter">
                    Component footer
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS looks as follows respectively:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.componentHeader {
    height: 50px; 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 5px dotted black;
}

.componentContent {
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 5px dotted black; 
    top: 0px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.componentFooter {
    height: 50px; 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 5px dotted black;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

JSFiddle of the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/Visa/ufnzwdce/11/

P.S. if someone has a better implementation for this situation, please let me know!

Comment: I just tried this in FF 41, Chrome 46, IE 9, and IE 11, and it works as you describe that it should - to varying degrees of fluency.

Comment: Something that is interesting... In IE 11, only changing the *height* of the window has some issues.  Changing both the height and width does invoke more real-time updates of the inner content's height and scrollbar.

Comment: For some reason the fluency really varies a lot between FF and Chrome. With IE changing only the window height doesn't trigger the change in content height but changing height and width at the same time gives the desired result. Any suggestions how to get it more fluent?

Comment: At this point, I would probably start looking at a JavaScript solution to help with the differences in CSS implementation.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the same structure without calc function? I realized that calc isn't the best option when it comes to supporting mobile browsers...